# C# Detect macro buttons from keyboard console app

Tags: c#, keyboard, console-application

I was planing on making a simple console app to run in the background at all time. I want to run a function based by key press and I need a button(s) that is not in use. So tried to get the app to react on macro key presses but cant figure out how to do it. 
The basic stuff like ReadLine key.. etc is not working

(It's the 5 extra buttons on the left)

[image]

Comment: Awesome!  What code did you try?

Comment: @Trey Readkey Line etc...  the basic cant come up with something else to try

Comment: it really depends on what keyboard. the macros might be only controlled by the keyboard controller itself and nothing your operating system sees.

Comment: @DanielA.White Yeah that might be the case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at your picture I think we are talking about a Razer Keyboard here.
I have the same one and when I look into the Synapse Software to see what the macro buttons actually do, I see that they are disabled by the default

You can configure them to press a certain key, key combo or something like that.
So my approach would be to configure the macro to some kind of key-combo and listen for that in your app. (Obviously this would only work on your machine and require extra setup for any other user using your tool)